# What's the best way to combine one of mediawiki languages and then export the result to formatted pdf?

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, liferay, mediawiki

I need your help because I'm confusing about what's the best way to solve this problem.

**The Problem:**
I need to implement a solution using mediawiki to construct collaborative manuals and then export the result to one formatted pdf, where people can download it in only one file.

**The Cenario:**
I'm using liferay wiki's and there I have the option to choose between three language formats, Creole, MediaWiki and HTML.

I don't know what's the best way or the best program i can use to export the results of wiki collaboration to one formated pdf.

**The Doubts:**
What's the best language formats to use in wiki and then what's the easier way to export the wiki pages to a formatted pdf using css stylesheet?

Thanks for regards.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most robust and well-supported tool for exporting wiki pages as a PDF is [Extension:Collection](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCollection) (which uses [Extension:PDF_Writer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPDF_Writer)); this is the one used by WikiMedia Foundation for their sites. Wiki Markup Language works fine with this extension, so you don't need to bother with HTML or anything else.